# Where did the Tribble noises come from?

Tags: star-trek, foley

Star Trek's [Tribbles](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tribble) are known for two distinctive sounds they make: a soothing coo/purr noise when they're petted, and a harsh, grinding shriek to express their dislike of Klingons.  Have the cast or crew ever talked about where those sounds came from?

Comment: My hairless Guinea pig makes the same sound a tribble makes when they are happy and calm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Memory Alpha article for the episode ***The Trouble with Tribbles***](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Trouble_with_Tribbles_(episode)):

> Sound effects editor Douglas Grindstaff combined altered dove coos, screech owl cries and emptying balloons to create the tribble sounds.

Comment: Wow. I came so close. I looked at the Memory Alpha article for Tribbles, but not the episode they appeared in! \*sadface\*